# Date Field from CSV file not Loading in DSV Loader(Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, require

I'm trying to Load date field in Csv file into Node.js using dsv-Loader and printing the output in console. The csv file is in the same folder as the js file.

**CSV file(zillow.csv)**

```
date,close
31-03-2017,16
```

**Node.js Code**

```
 var data = require('./zillow.csv');
 console.log(data)
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

I can't understand where I'm going wrong in such a simple step. Please Help!!

Comment: The `require` function is for importing javascript code only (specifcally Node.js modules). You can't just require any type of file and expect it to work. Take a look at using a library like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Answer (score 0):

You cann't require a csv file because the csv content isn't a object content

You can require a json file instead of csv.

To do that, follow these steps:

1. Create a new json file called `mydata.json` in the same directory

`mydata.json` contains your data:

```
{
  "0": {"date": "31-03-2017", "close": 16},
  "1": {"date": "15-04-2017", "close": 1},
  "2": {"date": "25-05-2017", "close": 22}
}
```

In your node.js code :

```
var data = require('./mydata.json');
console.log(data);
```

**The result is** :

```
{ '0': { date: '31-03-2017', close: 16 },
  '1': { date: '15-04-2017', close: 1 },
  '2': { date: '25-05-2017', close: 22 } }

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package : [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) that parse and format the csv content: